# Get progress of an async call

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, webclient, imgur

I'm using a block of code I got from a blog, to upload images to IMGur using API v3.

It works fine, but I wanted to implement a progress bar system to let the user know how much has been uploaded, if the program deals with high res images.

So far I haven't been able to do so.

I'm not an experienced coder, just doing this as a learning project.

The Code:

```
public object UploadImage(string image) 
{ 
    WebClient w = new WebClient();
    w.UploadProgressChanged += (s, e) => { };
    w.UploadValuesCompleted += (s, e) => { };
    w.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + ClientId);
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Keys = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection(); 
    try 
    { 
        Keys.Add("image", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(image))); 
        byte[] responseArray = w.UploadValues("https://api.imgur.com/3/image", Keys);


        dynamic result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray); System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("link\":\"(.*?)\""); 
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = reg.Match(result); 
        string url = match.ToString().Replace("link\":\"", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace("\\/", "/");
        textBox1.Text = url;
        return url; 
    }
    catch (Exception s) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong. " + s.Message); 
            return "Failed!"; 
    } 
}
```

At first I tried using the events `UploadProgressChanged` and `UploadValuesCompleted`, but they are not triggered, my theory is they are triggered when `UploadValuesAsync` is called instead of `UploadValues`.

1. How do I implement a progress system?
2. What is the difference between async and normal transfer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between aync and normal transfer is, that the `UploadValues` method will block the current thread until all data has been transferred. Because the thread is blocked in this time you can't catch any events too. Therefore you have to use the asynchrony method `UploadValuesAsync` which will transfer the data in the background and you're able to go on with the execution of your code.
The `UploadProgressChanged` only fires for the `UploadValuesAsync` too. Your code should look something like this (**Not tested!**):

```
public String UploadImage(string image) 
    { 
        WebClient w = new WebClient();

        w.UploadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            myProgressBar.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToSend;
            myProgressBar.Value = (int)e.BytesSent;
        };

        w.UploadValuesCompleted += new UploadValuesCompletedEventHandler(UploadComplete);

        w.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + ClientId);
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Keys = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection(); 
        try 
        { 
            Keys.Add("image", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(image))); 
            w.UploadValuesAsync("https://api.imgur.com/3/image", Keys);

            return "Uploading..";
        } catch (Exception s) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong. " + s.Message); 
                return "Failed!"; 
        } 
    }

public void UploadComplete(Object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    myProgressBar.Value = 100;

    byte[] responseArray = e.Result;
    dynamic result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray); 
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("link\":\"(.*?)\""); 
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = reg.Match(result); 
    string url = match.ToString().Replace("link\":\"", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace("\\/", "/");
    textBox1.Text = url;
}
```

**Edit**
I moved the code after the `UploadValuesAsync` call into the `w.UploadValuesCompleted`. You can find the server response in the `Result` field of the `UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs` class which is passed to the event in the variable `e`.
Your method `UploadImage` will now return *Uploading* when the progress started and you'll have to do your rest work in the `w.UploadValuesCompleted` event.

Comment: UploadValuesAsync returns void while UploadValues returns a byte array, any suggestions?

Comment: You may need to move the code after the `UploadValuesAsync` call in the `UploadValuesCompleated` event handler and read the result from `e.Result`. I will update my answer as soon as I'm back home.

Comment: Okay I updated my code now, still not tested. Let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code did not work, but it did point me in the right direction, thanks!, e.Result() returns a byte[] instead of a string, so I took it into the old responseArray bytearray and it worked flawlessly.
A point I want to note for others,
e.ProgressPercentage does not work;
I used 
                myProgressBar.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToSend;
                myProgressBar.Value = (int)e.BytesSent;

Comment: btw for code efficiency and easy-to-read, is it better to use lambda expressions, or normal method-like structure?

Comment: Yep, you're right, `e.Result` returns a string in case of `UploadStringCompleted`, I miss read that. I think you should use a normal method in your case because it's easier to read because you have some more code in this lambda block. I choose lambds for verry short code, as seen in your `w.UploadProgressChanged` block and normal methods if I have some more work to do there. I updated my code to be funtional.